# Cleanup in a generator when it goes out of scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, generator

I have a generator that must perform a clean up step even if it was never iterated through:

```
def gen(data):
    while True:
        item = data.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        # ...
        try:
            yield transformed_item
        except GeneratorExit:
            break
    # clean up; must happen if gen was called
    # ...
```

Everything works fine (i.e., clean up happens) when I call it like this:

```
for x in gen(data):
    # ...
```

or like this:

```
g = gen(data)
r = next(g)
# ...
```

But when the generator goes out of scope without anyone calling `next` on it, then of course it never executes any code at all, so `GeneratorExit` isn't raised inside it, and the clean-up doesn't happen:

```
g = gen(data)
# g was never used before going out of scope
del g
```

How can I refactor the code to guarantee the cleanup step occurs even if the generator goes out of scope before it ever had a chance to yield anything?

Comment: You should be able to override the `__del__()` method on your generator to handle this. It's not pretty, but it will be invoked when the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use context handlers for this.  It depends how long you need to persist the generator.

```
class Gen(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._gen(self.data)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Cleanup
        print 'Cleaning up'

    def _gen(self, data):
        for i in data:
            yield i
```

Then it would look like:

```
with Gen(data) as g:
    r = next(g)
```

EDIT:

Given the limitation that you can't enforce end users to use context managers, could you just wrap the generator creation in another function and "seed" the generator?

```
def gen(data):
    g = _gen(data)
    next(g)
    return g


def _gen(data):
    yield None
    while True:
        ... # Rest of generator
```

Comment: The generator is used in client code, so I have no control over how long it needs to persist. So unfortunately, I can't impose the constraint that the generator can only be used through a context manager.

Comment: @max I added a solution that could work.  What if you just wrapped the generator and forced it to iterate once with a junk value?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! You can even do it without `yield None`: just `g = gen(data)` and then `return itertools.chain([next(g)], g)`. Still I get a feeling that the generator designers didn't think cleaning up generators that never ran was a good use case -- otherwise, they'd support it with a more idiomatic API. I wonder if I'm missing a better approach.

Comment: @max Cleanup is generally achieved with `try/finally` blocks (which context managers help wrap). Even if the generator wasn't started, there's no guarantee that the entire generator will be exhausted and thus get cleaned up at the end.

Comment: Correction: `g = gen(data)` and then `return itertools.chain([next(g)], g)` as I suggested would prematurely obtain the input; in general, this may be unacceptable.